# Global variable for the server instance in C++

Tags: c++

When looking at some existing code for a web server, I see that there's a `main.cc` file and another `server.h` and `server.cc` pair for the server class.

```
// main.cc
#include "server.h"
int main() {
  foo::server = new foo::Server();
  server->Serve();  // runs forever
}

// server.cc
namespace foo {
  Server *server;

  // class member definitions ...
}
```

Is there a good reason not to just define `foo::Server *server` in main?

What are the pros and cons of this coding style?

Comment: Rule of thumb: do not use globals, or pointers, if they're not actually needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

For maintenance. It's intuitive that you have the definition of `foo::server` in `server.cc`. If you only have one variable, the benefit is not directly visible. But say you have dozens of variables. With this style, you know exactly where to look for the definition.

Comment: It's about variable definition, not class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is analogical to declared `cout` **object** in `iostream` lib. Most of the time there is only one object of `ostream` class, so why not to create it once visible everywere (where `iostrem` is included)?